# Factory Reset MacBook but it is in Japanese

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Air (A1466). I do not know the password for the screen lock. It has been set on Japanese (I only know English).

I can not do a Factory Reset because I don't understand Japanese. Can anyone walk me through Factory Reset, while it is in Japanese? How do I change the language of my MacBook if it is in Japanese, but I do not know the password?

Comment: Can you boot to internet recovery?

Answer (score 1):

The OS Controls language. You will need to boot a different OS to that machine and run through the set up assistant to choose a different language for the new OS or you need someone to make you a new user account on that machine to change the OS.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

The only thing that can foil this plan is if there's a firmware password on the Mac. That would prevent you from Internet booting to recovery or bringing another external  OS to the Mac

Answer (score 0):

There's a nifty trick you can try and do to trick macOS into thinking it hasn't been setup yet.

- Restart the MacBook with **Command + S** held down to get to the Single User mode (essentially Terminal)
- Check the filesystem with `fsck -fy`
- Mount the root drive as mountable with `mount -uw /`
- Carefully type `rm /var/db/.applesetupdone`  which removes the file the MacBook checks for when updating the software
- Type `reboot` to reboot the MacBook and you'll be presented with the first step of setting up macOS which is Language Selection

Hope this helps!

**Please be careful when fiddling with Single User mode as mistypes can cause a lot of issues with your system**